# Deleting files from every user directory in Batch

Tags: batch-file

The plan was to uninstall flash player and cleanup the folders for every user on the device.

```
%CD%\uninstall_flash_player.exe -uninstall

IF EXIST "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash"(
        rd /q /s "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash" 
    )

for /d %%a in (C:\Users\*) do (
    IF EXIST "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player"(
        rd /q /s "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Flash Player" 
    )
    IF EXIST "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player"(
        rd /q /s "%%a\AppData\Roaming\Macromedia\Flash Player" 
    )
)
pause
```

Problem is the folders don't get deleted but the uninstall went just fine.

Comment: And what have you tried to debug this problem? Is there any error message you want to share?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this, how do I debug a batch file? It just disappears instantly.

Comment: When you use the point-click-and-giggle method of executing a batch, the batch window will often close if a syntax-error is found. You should instead [open a 'command prompt'](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) and run your batch from there so that the window remains open and any error message will be displayed.

Comment: The problem with the code you have written is that you must always have a space character directly before an opening parenthesis. Just add the missing three spaces.

Comment: Ok it was me being stupid in the morning I wasn't using runas thanks for the info though everyone